# css3 webkit transition width auto on focus

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

[Please check this demo first](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/MgcDU/1950/embedded/result/)

If you focus the search box it will expand to 400px.

Thats because I set the width to 400px on focus

```
.navbar-search .search-query:focus {
 width:400px;
-moz-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
-webkit-transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
transition: width 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

I would like to have 100% width search on focus.

Can anyone help me with this?

[Here is the source code.](http://jsfiddle.net/Viruthagiri/MgcDU/1950/)

Comment: 100% width of what? The whole navbar? If so what would happen to the nav links? Or do you man you want it to take up all the remaining width left over by the nav links?

Comment: @BillyMoat Yes I want my search bar take up all the remaining width left over by the nav links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following rules:

```
.navbar-search {
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
.navbar-search .search-query {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 30px;
}
.navbar-search .search-query:focus {
  width: 100%;
}
```